# How does `curl` on the command line determine the MIME type of a file being uploaded?

Tags: command-line, curl, mime-types

When uploading a file as a form field in `curl` (for example, `curl -F 'file=@path/to/file' https://example.org/upload`), `curl` sometimes sets the [MIME type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3828381/6771046) differently than what is returned by other utilities determining MIME type.

For example, on `.bmp` bitmap files, `file -i path/to/file.bmp` says it's `image/x-ms-bmp`, but `curl` sets the MIME type to `application/octet-stream` unless I explicitly override it.

However, it works properly for some file types, such as `.png` and `.jpg`.

I would like to know how it determines the MIME type and under what conditions it will work as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From some source code spelunking for `Content-Type` `curl` appears to do some file extension matching otherwise defaulting to `HTTPPOST_CONTENTTYPE_DEFAULT` which is `application/octet-stream`, in the oddly named `ContentTypeForFilename` function:

https://github.com/curl/curl/blob/ee56fdb6910f6bf215eecede9e2e9bfc83cb5f29/lib/formdata.c#L166

```
static const char *ContentTypeForFilename(const char *filename,
                                          const char *prevtype)
{
  const char *contenttype = NULL;
  unsigned int i;
  /*
   * No type was specified, we scan through a few well-known
   * extensions and pick the first we match!
   */
  struct ContentType {
    const char *extension;
    const char *type;
  };
  static const struct ContentType ctts[]={
    {".gif",  "image/gif"},
    {".jpg",  "image/jpeg"},
    {".jpeg", "image/jpeg"},
    {".txt",  "text/plain"},
    {".html", "text/html"},
    {".xml", "application/xml"}
  };

  if(prevtype)
    /* default to the previously set/used! */
    contenttype = prevtype;
  else
    contenttype = HTTPPOST_CONTENTTYPE_DEFAULT;

  if(filename) { /* in case a NULL was passed in */
    for(i = 0; i<sizeof(ctts)/sizeof(ctts[0]); i++) {
      if(strlen(filename) >= strlen(ctts[i].extension)) {
        if(strcasecompare(filename +
                          strlen(filename) - strlen(ctts[i].extension),
                          ctts[i].extension)) {
          contenttype = ctts[i].type;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  /* we have a contenttype by now */
  return contenttype;
}
```

(Though I suppose the source could be modified to do `file(1)` type magic checks in the future, maybe...)

Comment: Thanks! Seems like this would be a fairly easy thing to patch for more file support at one point, and something better than simply using the file extension.

Comment: Yeah you could save PNG data or whatever as a `foo.jpg` and then who knows how bad it gets depending on what the server and any other software does with that...